# Как решить задачу Python, операции со словарем

Tags: python, словари, dict

Изучаю python, застрял на такой задаче:

> A `some_iterable` хранит слова из предложения. Используйте понимание словаря для создания нового словаря, в котором ключами будут слова из `some_iterable`, написанные прописными буквами, а значениями-те же слова, написанные строчными буквами. Распечатайте этот словарь.

> Вы можете использовать `upper()` и `lower()` методы для строк, чтобы преобразовать все символы в верхний и нижний регистры соответственно.

пробовал решить так:

```
some_iterable = input().split()
some_iterable = {}
for key, value in some_iterable.items():
    some_iterable(k).upper
    some_iterable(v).lower
print(some_iterable)
```

Comment: изначально предложение берется из input()? вы затираете его во второй строке

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы затираете some_iterable во второй строке, попробуйте так:

```
some_iterable = input().split()
result_dict = {word.lower(): word.upper() for word in some_iterable}
print(result_dict)
```

Для

```
>? мама МЫЛА РаМу
```

выдаст:

```
{'мама': 'МАМА', 'мыла': 'МЫЛА', 'раму': 'РАМУ'}
```

Comment: спасибо, очень помогло

Answer (score 2):

Похоже, у вас проблемы не со словарями, а с общим непониманием того, что именно вы делаете. Читаем первые три строки:

```
some_iterable = input().split()
some_iterable = {}
for key, value in some_iterable.items():
```

Первая строка -  читаем вход, делим на слова, результат загоняем в переменную `some_iterable`.

Вторая строка -  стираем нафиг все, что было в переменной  `some_iterable` и создаем другую переменную с тем-же именем, но теперь будем считать, что она у нас типа "словарь".

Третья строка -  из этой, заведомо пустой, определенной в предыдущей строке переменной  начинаем что-ты пытаться вытягивать.

Дальше что-то комментировать не приходиться.   Все ошибки - на глазах. Исправляйте. И все остальное заработает.

Comment: спасибо за развернутый комментарий, буду разбираться

Answer (score 2):

а так чем не устраивает?

```
some_iterable = input().split()
res = dict((word.lower(), word.upper()) for word in some_iterable)
```

Comment: спасибо за помощь